# Situacion hipotética -- "could/might/may have... done it..."

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, tiempos-verbales, condicional

Digamos que he perdido mi libro **y no  sé dónde**. Uno de los lugares donde estaba yo fue una cafetería. Entonces, vuelvo allí a averiguar esto. Lo que hubiese dicho en ingles sería:

- I **could/might/may have left** my book here...

Cómo se lo diría en Español?

Hay dos opciones en los que pienso, pero puede ser que ninguna sea correcta:

1. **Puede/pude haberla dejado** mi libro aquí
2. **Podría haberla dejado** mi libro aquí

Pero! En ambos casos la idea, **me parece,** es que "si .. pudo/podría ... pero seguramente **no lo hice en ese momento** " -- y esto no es lo que quiero preguntar, porque no lo sé si lo hice (la dejé) o no.

Cómo preguntaríalo entonces? Desde punto de vista de la gramatica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola!

Respecto a las opciones que planteas, tal y como las tienes escritas debes utilizar "pude" (Pretérito perfecto simple), el "puede" no sería correcto (al final del mensaje explico cuáles serían las opciones con "puede"):

**1. Puede/pude haberLA dejado mi libro aquí**

Sobra el "LA" porque después ya explicas lo que pudiste dejar (el libro). Así, las dos opciones que salen de aquí serían:

```
  1.1 Pude haber dejado mi libro aquí

  1.2 Pude haberlo dejado aquí (con "lo" porque libro es masculino)
```

**2. Podría haberLA dejado mi libro aquí**

Misma idea que en la primera opción, el "la" sobra (y sería "lo") si después hablas del libro

```
  2.1 Podría haber dejado mi libro aquí

  2.2 Podría haberlo dejado aquí
```

En cualquier caso, ninguna de las opciones me parece adecuada para expresar lo que entiendo que quieres decir ya que, aunque no haya fallo gramatical, a la hora de hablar, **ese "puede" se podría entender como capacidad cuando en realidad quieres hacer referencia a una posibilidad de que algo haya sucedido**. Mis alternativas serían las siguientes:

```
 A. Quizás dejé mi libro aquí 
 B. Quizás lo dejé aquí
```

Y utilizando el "puede" que mencionas en el mensaje inicial, las opciones serían:

```
 C. Puede QUE (me) dejase el libro aquí
 D. Puede QUE (me) lo dejase aquí
 E. Puede QUE (me) haya dejado el libro aquí
 F. Puede QUE (me) lo haya dejado aquí
```

En las 4 opciones anteriores el "me" es opcional, son válidas las frases con o sin él.

**EDITADO:**

A raíz del comentario a este mensaje, matizo lo siguiente. Para empezar, todas pueden servir para casos en los que no se sabe el resultado final, pero las respuesta de letra (A, B,. . . ,F) las considero más adecuadas. Mi clasificación sería:

- Se sabe el resultado final: 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2
- No se sabe el resultado final: A, B, C, D, E, F

Agrego otro ejemplo con el que igual se entiende mejor:

**CUANDO SE SABE EL RESULTADO**

- Miguel PUDO jugar en el Real Madrid . . .
- Miguel PUDO (o PODRÍA) HABER jugado en el Real Madrid . . .

. . . pero tuvo una lesión grave que se lo impidió

**CUANDO NO SE SABE EL RESULTADO**

- QUIZÁS Miguel jugó en el Real Madrid . . .
- PUEDE QUE Miguel jugase (o haya jugado) en el Real Madrid . . .

. . . pero no lo recuerdo bien, porque fue hace mucho tiempo.

Comment: `Podría haberlo dejado aquí` / `Podría haber dejado mi libro aquí` -- en tantos casos hay 2 opciones  a) `Podría...` pero no lo hice realmente y lo sé (se sabe) b) `Podría...` pero no sé si realmente lo hice (dejé) o no (no se sabe). Correcto?

Comment: a) se sabe el resultado final b) no se sabe el resultado final

Comment: @jundoderu, añado una explicación en el mensaje que espero te ayude a entender mejor la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Los dos ejemplos que planteas son gramaticalmente incorrectos.

Lo correcto es:

> Pude haber dejado mi libro aquí?

o

> He dejado mi libro aquí?

Comment: Tu respuesta es correcta, pero estaría bien que explicaras por qué la tuya lo es y la que propone en la pregunta no (es decir, explicar por qué sobra el "la" de haberla, etc.)

Comment: Pude haber dejado mi libro aquí? = **Can I have left my book here?**

Answer (score 0):

Otros ejemplos de contestación

- ¿Ha visto por aquí algún libro?
- ¿Sabe si he dejado por aquí algún libro?
- ¿Por casualidad ha visto un libro de..."Matemáticas"...?
- He perdido mi libro de..."Matemáticas"..., por favor, si lo encuentra ¿puede guardarlo? Gracias.
- Hola, estoy buscando y no lo encuentro, podría estar atento, he perdido un libro de...Matemáticas... y no se si lo he dejado aquí. Gracias.
- ¿Podría haber dejado mi libro por aquí?
- ¿Pude haber dejado un libro por aquí?

Comment: No has entendido la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

I **could have** left my book here. [dos sentidos, condicional o pasado]
I **might have** left my book here. [might puede ser pasado de may o mas fuerte que may]

- *Es posible* que haya dejado mi libro aqui. [presente]
- *Puede* que haya dejado mi libro aqui. [presente]
- *Pude* haberlo dejado aqui. [pasado]
- *Podría* haberlo dejado aqui. [condicional]

might, may y could serían subjuntivo en español.

could, might, may en las frases arriba expresan una posibilidad, es un verbo modal pero también pueden ser ideas en el pasado.

Comment: Eso es una parte de mi pregunta. Pero falta la segunda

Comment: @jundoderu No sé lo que quieres decirme, lamento. Está hablando del condicional?? "si .. pudo/podría ... pero seguramente no lo hice en ese momento". If I could have done it, I would have done it. If I could do it, I would. Eso?

Comment: `Pero! En ambos casos la idea, me parece, es que "si .. pudo/podría ... pero seguramente no lo hice en ese momento " -- y esto no es lo que quiero preguntar, porque no lo sé si lo hice (la dejé) o no.`

Comment: La pergunta es para: I could/might/may have left my book here...y después  tu añades "me parece" etc. con si.  Pero el inglés could/might/may have left no contiene la idea de if: Es otra pregunta. Otro punto: En inglés, un "if" no se pone en proposiciones con might y may por lo general. ¿¿"Abre los ojos" quién pues?

Comment: si .. pudo/podría ... pero seguramente no lo hice en ese momento " Esto lo cambia.